# Struts how to insert bean:write in bean:message arguments

Tags: struts

I try to do that, but it does not work.

```
<logic:present name="MEMBER" >
<bean:message key="member.registerConfirmation" arg0='<bean:write name="MEMBRE_REGISTER" property="firstname"/>' arg1='<bean:write name="MEMBRE_REGISTER" property="lastname"/>'/>
</logic:present>
```

and bean:message contain:

```
member.registerConfirmation = Congratulations {0} {1}, you are in !
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try EL with bean:message

Something like this.

```
<bean:message key="member.registerConfirmation" arg0='${MEMBRE_REGISTER.firstname}' arg1='${MEMBRE_REGISTER.lastname}'/>
```

Comment: One note: the args are unescaped, making them vulnerable to XSS attacks. You can address that by doing: `<c:set var="firstNameEscaped"><c:out value="${MEMBRE_REGISTER.firstname}"/></c:set>` and then doing  `arg0='${firstNameEscaped}'` etc.